# Javascript delete navigator object

Tags: javascript

In a JavaScript `window` object, there's a `navigator` object, which has lots of properties describing the clients browser, one of which is an array called `plugins`. I'm trying to disable this in my personal browser (chrome) by having JavaScript injected after the execution of every webpage I view. In other words, I don't want my plugins to be exposed to the websites I visit.

So I wrote this to be included with every HTTP(S) response on Chrome:

```
(function(window) {
    delete window.navigator;
}(window));
```

But the navigator is still there, because in the console when I test it I see:

[image]

However, when I manually type `delete navigator` in the console, it works!

[image]

So why is it not working with my JavaScript? It's not a matter of if the script is executing, I've confirmed that it is, its just not removing the navigator object. Any ideas? I've also tried setting it to an empty object, but nothing is unsetting it...

Comment: Are you loading that script from the bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes, and I've tried it with a setTimeout() as well, in case of conflicting scripts, also didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

As of now in Chrome, window.navigator and apis exposed via window.navigator seem to be read-only and simply calling `delete` on them won't have any effect.

For testing purposes I've been using `Object.defineProperty` to define a getter that returns null. this works well when a script or polyfill on the page tries to test for the existance of a specific browser api:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'navigator', {
          get() {
            return null;
          },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `window.navigator` to another value. You can make it an empty array or object.

```
window.navigator = [];
```

or

```
window.navigator = {};
```

Either way, the values stored in navigator should be gone after redefining it.

Comment: I've tried that, I've tried setting everything... window.navigator, window.navigator.plugins, setting to: {}, [], new Object(), everything... The problem with reassignment is there is no internal setter method, so it won't allow any kind of reassignment of navigator object, even in the console, it reverts back immediately

Comment: In that case, your chances of deleting window.navigator are pretty slim. From what I've seen, redefining it has been possible in certain browsers, but it appears that your browser does not support this.